# LINQ in ngFor Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I get some 15 different lookup list values in the `component.ts` and i assign each to a list and bind it to the `<select>` in html. This works fine.

To make this code more in a cleaner way, is there anything like this?

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-label>Preferred Job</mat-label>
              <mat-select>
                 <mat-option *ngFor="let job of designationList.filter(x=>x.lookupName === 'Designation')" [value]="job.id">
                  {{job.lookupValue}}
                </mat-option> 
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Kind of `where` or `filter` condition could directly be applied in the `<select>` so that i can no longer use separate list for each dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom function for this variable.

*component.ts*

```
filteredDesignationList(loopUpName: string){
    return this.designationList.filter(x=>x.lookupName === loopUpName)"
}
```

*component.html*

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-label>Preferred Job</mat-label>
              <mat-select>
                 <mat-option *ngFor="let job of filteredDesignationList('Designation') [value]="job.id">
                  {{job.lookupValue}}
                </mat-option> 
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Can a get accessor have parameters?

Comment: Of course, there is a parameter in my example. You can edit accessors whatever you want. Just don't forget to return something.

Comment: the compile error i get is "A 'get' accessor cannot have parameters." ? any clues

Comment: I am so sorry for wrong information. I check it and you are true. I am editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use a Pipe to filter your data instead of using the filter directly.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let job of designationList|filter-pipe" [value]="job.id">
              {{job.lookupValue}}
</mat-option>
```

And take a look at this to learn how to implement a pipe:

https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: this might be helpful too:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254511/got-error-when-i-used-custom-pipe-in-ngfor

Comment: Hello, maybe this one also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor

Comment: @nevzatopcu thats what exactly what i want  and it was cleaner. thanks

Comment: @MohammadrezaImani thanks for pointing to a elegant and functional way.

Comment: your welcome but the angular concept is to use pipe here.